# WCF POST json not working

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service, i am trying to do a POST to it using a browser based rest client.

It hits the service if i pass nothing in the body but if i add a json to it then it says "400 Bad request". Please advice

> **Error**

[image]

> **Contract**

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate="AddEmployee", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string AddEmployee(Employee emp);
```

> **"Config"**

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="GLOpenSourceService.GLOpenSourceService">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="GLOpenSourceService.IGLOpenSourceService" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/GLOpenSourceService" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

> **Employee Model class**

```
 public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> JoiningDate { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLogin { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

> **Department**

```
 public partial class Department
    {
        public Department()
        {
            this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentHead { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The error is bad request! Your JSON seems to be incorrect. Also, try changing Content-Type: application/json; charset= utf-8

Comment: Verify your Employee model maps to the JSON you are passing.

Comment: Also share your Employee Model class

Comment: Added models to the question

Comment: Worked for me as soon as i removed "BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest"